# Run PHP crone multiple time in a timeframe

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a PHP cron job and i  need to run it on 10 times in between 10PM to 11PM
Is it possible in my server

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/geniusgr/public_html/cron.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this cron:

```
*/6 22 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/geniusgr/public_html/cron.php
```

It will run every 6 minutes at 22 (10PM):

```
22.00 -  1st
22.06 -  2nd
22.12 -  3rd
22.18 -  4th
22.24 -  5th
22.30 -  6th
22.36 -  7th
22.42 -  8th
22.48 -  9th
22.54 - 10th
```

Comment: if i need it for 3 hours what to do..? like 5pm to 10 pm..need to run it on every 15 min?

Comment: Well you have to check how many minutes you need to put in between. 3 hours is 180 minutes, so if you want 10 times you should indicate every 180/10=18 mins. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info for the correct formats and debugging.